# Assigning a path as a variable in bash file

Tags: 18.04, bash, bashrc

I am new in linux and  I am trying to assign a path into a variable as follows

```
#! /bin/bash

path=/usr/local/driveworks/tools/capture

cd path

./video_exporter ///media/uuresin/SSD3/last_record/input.lraw ~/records/output.mp4
```

The bash file above produces the following error:

```
./trial.sh: line 5: cd: path: No such file or directory
./trial.sh: line 7: ./video_exporter: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have modified my bash file as follows and it worked!

```
#! /bin/bash

path=/usr/local/driveworks/tools/capture

cd $path

...
```

Comment: also it is good practice to put bash variables when calling them between double quotes so `cd "$path"` would be better practice.